# append epoch date at the beginning of a file in bash

Tags: regex, bash

I have a list of 20 files, 10 of them already have 1970-01-01- at the beginning of the name and 10 does not ( the remaining ones all start with a small letter ) .

So my task was to rename those files that do not have the epoch date in the beginning with the epoch date too. Using bash, the below code works, but I could not solve it using a regular expression for example using rename. I had to extract the basename and then further mv. An elegant solution would be just use one pipe instead of two.

Works

```
find ./ -regex './[a-z].*' | xargs -I {}  basename {} | xargs -I {} mv {} 1970-01-01-{}
```

Hence looking for a solution with just one xargs or -exec?

Comment: did you try `rename 's/^([a-z])/1970-01-01-$1/' *.txt`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just use a single `rename` command:

```
rename -n 's/^([a-z])/1970-01-01-$1/' *
```

Assuming you're operating on all the files present in current directory.

Note that `-n` flag (dry run) will only show intended actions by `rename` command but won't really rename any files.

If you want to combine with `find` then use:

```
find . -type f -maxdepth 1 -name '[a-z]*.txt' -execdir rename -n 's/^/1970-01-01-/' {} +
```

Comment: haha, how simple, I got jumbled in the find and exec loop. Can you still edit your answer with a find and exec/xargs? I just want to know to learn, where I was going wrong.

Comment: The reason, is there are some files in the folder like 1991-10-10-xyz.txt that also needs to be renamed to 1970-01-01-xyz.txt. So, I wanted to pick up the needy files using the find command first.

Comment: Using `find` you can do: `find . -type f -maxdepth 1 -name '[a-z]*.txt' -execdir rename -n 's/^/1970-01-01-/' {} +` and then you can tweak this `-name` option or `rename` pattern.

Comment: I still dont understand if -name can take regular expression, what is the signifigance of -regex ?? But its a different question altogether. Thank you for the answer.

Comment: `-name` doesn't take a regex. It takes a glob pattern that may look like regex but is very different from a regex.

Answer (score 0):

I always prefer readable code over short code.

```
r() {
  base=$(basename "$1")
  dir=$(dirname "$1")
  if [[ "$base" =~ ^1970-01-01- ]]
  then
    : "ignore, already has correct prefix"
  else
    echo mv "$1" "$dir/1970-01-01-$base"
  fi
}
export -f r

find . -type f -exec bash -c 'r {}' \;
```

This also just prints out what would have been done (for testing).  Remove the `echo` before the `mv` to have to real thing.

Mind that the `mv` will overwrite existing files (if there is a ./a/b/c and an ./a/b/1970-01-01-c already).  Use option `-i` to `mv` to be save from this.